# Getting error while writing script to create a table

Tags: sql-server

I am working on sql server 2005.
I am writing a T sql script which will need to add a table to the database,
but i want to add the check that if the table is already created.
But my script is giving me this error message:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near 'ON'.
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 1
There is already an object named 'DeliveryChargeRegion' in the database.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

Comment: Without seeing your script it's hard to debug...

Comment: Please provide the script, otherwise I have to say "not a real question."

Answer (score 1):

```
IF not  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TABLENAME]') AND type in (N'U'))

begin

-- Create table.

end
```

GO

Answer (score 1):

This code is similar to that generated by SSMS:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[TABLE_NAME_HERE]') AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
    -- CREATE TABLE HERE
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
if object_id('tablename') is NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE tableName

END
```

Nothing wrong with the sys.objects approach, I just find the above easier to write and read...

Comment: I dont think it checks specifically for tables. It could be any kind of object with that name.

Comment: Oh, it definitely doesn't, it is any kind of database object, good point, thanks...

Comment: Not a error message, simply that if an object is undefined, it's object id is NULL.   You can use the code example above to check for stored procedures, functions, etc.